# Getting variables out of a structure - c

Tags: c

I have a struct with variables in it.
How do I access the variables of a struct if the struct is passed as a reference?

```
struct point {
    float x;
};

float function(struct point *p)
{
    return p.x;
}
```

... in another words, what do I need to change in the body of the function for it not to cause an error?

Comment: Two options: p->x or (*p).x;

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
struct point {
    float x;
};

// return variable 'x' of pointer 'p'
float function(struct point *p)
{
    return p->x;
}
```

`p->x` is equivalent to `(*p).x`. When you pass a `struct *` (pointer to struct), you must access it as a pointer.

Comment: yeah `p` is a pointer

Comment: @melpomene Fair point; edited.